# Bounty expired with accepted answer but not given

Tags: support, bounty

There was a bounty on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043114/how-can-i-add-a-recordingcontroller-in-a-jmeter-project-using-java-api) and I posted an answer which was accepted and after the bounty is over (and grace period) I didn't receive any bounty points, although in bounty [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) it stated I should:

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

Is the FAQ not updated or the bounty auto award not working or can there be a delay of few days?

Any comment will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That answer wasn't posted during the bounty period.

Check the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49043114/timeline).

The answer was posted **before** the bounty started, so it's not eligible for bounty auto-awarding.

Editing the answer during the bounty period doesn't count as posting the answer during the bounty period. I think there is FR somewhere about that, which got declined; but as it is currently implemented, editing doesn't count.

It is weird because the asker accepted your answer first, and then edited their question to show where were they stuck and posted the bounty...

Comment: I edit the question with different solution during the bounty period, it doesn't count?

Comment: I'd also add that another reason you wouldn't have gotten it anyway is that your answer doesn't have a minimum score of 2, which is another requirement for the auto-award.

Comment: @n8te since the answer was accepted and the bounty was started by the question owner, I think the minimum score doesn't apply. But timing still does.

Comment: Ahh ok. It didn't seem to specify that in the help center but I could have read it wrong.

Comment: @n8te, check the paragraph that the OP quoted in their question right up here.

Comment: You're right. I stand corrected.

Comment: *"It is weird because the asker accepted your answer first"* Well. The profile flair text does read *"I always pay it forward"*...

Comment: @Gimby And yet failed to award the bounty.

Comment: @yivi but that's paying afterwards! :)

Comment: Keep in mind that the bounty only ended 16 hours ago.  There is still ~8 hours of grace period left.